# Duplicate matches in template matching using OpenCV with C++

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I implemented a C++ code in OpenCv based on an OpenCV youtube Python tutorial:

This code is about matching a template to an image and getting occurences of it on the image. 
The masking step outputs the same regions as expected but the output shows both the expected regions and a set of duplicate values. I have two doubts

a)Why is there a duplication?

b)I had to offset the rectangles around the objects by a value. Which error caused this offset? I had to offset in only direction, leading me to believe that there is an error in the code rather than it being an intended function. Some regions at the bottom of the image have also been falsely marked as positive.

C++ Code:

```
int main(){
    Mat img,gray,temp,res,graytemp;
    img=imread("/home/robo123/Downloads/opencv-template-matching-python-tutorial.jpg",1);
    temp=imread("/home/robo123/Downloads/opencv-template-for-matching.jpg",1);
    cvtColor(img,gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    cvtColor(temp,graytemp,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    matchTemplate(gray,graytemp,res,TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
    double thresh = 0.78;
    threshold(res, res, thresh, 1., THRESH_BINARY);
    Mat rescolor;
    res.convertTo(rescolor, CV_8U, 255);
    int w,h,width,height;
    w=temp.rows;
    h=temp.cols;
    width=rescolor.rows;
    height=rescolor.cols;
    imshow("rescolor",rescolor);
    waitKey(0);


    for(int i=0;i<width;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<height;j++){
            Vec3b intensity = rescolor.at<cv::Vec3b>(j, i);
            uchar blue = intensity.val[0];
            uchar green = intensity.val[1];
            uchar red = intensity.val[2];
            if(blue!=0 || green!=0 || red!= 0){
                rectangle(img,Point(i+1.25*w,j),Point(i+2.25*w,j+h),Scalar(255,255,255),2,LINE_AA);
            }
        }
    imshow("IMage",img);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Python code from online[The code that I tried to write in C++]:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img_bgr=cv2.imread('opencv-template-matching-python-tutorial.jpg')
img_gray=cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

template= cv2.imread('opencv-template-for-matching.jpg',0)
w, h=template.shape[::-1]

res= cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold= 0.78
loc= np.where(res>= threshold)

for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_bgr, pt, (pt[0]+w,pt[1]+h), (0,255,255) ,2)

cv2.imshow('detected', img_bgr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml22l.png)
[Matches of the template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhvoX.jpg)

Comment: Maybe the Mat rescolor is 1-channel image but you are accessing it as 3-channel image with at<cv::Vec3b>. I don't see the reason why you need to convert the matching result to color. Try changing Vec3b to uchar.

Comment: You are right! I am struggling to assign a weighted combination of Vec3b values to a uchar matrix.

Comment: Figured out how to get around my previous limitation too. We have to split channels using cv::split to access each one as a single colour channel;